# Add to wishlist functionality review (React, Redux, Django Rest)

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux, tailwind-css

I need help and approval to analyze the following programming code. It is the first time that I have made a function of adding or removing, in a favorites button, a product from a wishlist.

I had the problem that, when rendering my component for the first time, if the product was already on the wishlist, the heart would be shown on, but it was always shown deactivated.

However, I applied the following programming logic:

```
const found = wishlist_items && wishlist_items.find((element) => element.product.id === parseInt(productId))

  const [isInWishList, setIsInWishList] = useState(found ? true : false)

  const addWishButton = () => {
    const handleToggleWishlist = async () => {
      if (isInWishList) {
        // Si ya está en la wishlist, elimínalo
        await remove_wishlist_item(productId);
      } else {
        // Si no está en la wishlist, agrégalo
        await add_wishlist_item(productId);
      }
      // Actualiza el estado para reflejar el cambio
      setIsInWishList(!isInWishList);
    };

    if (found) {
      return (
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={handleToggleWishlist}
          className="ml-4 py-3 px-3 rounded-md flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-500"
        >
          <HeartIcon className="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-red-600" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="sr-only">
            {isInWishList ? "Eliminar de favoritos" : "Agregar a favoritos"}
          </span>
        </button>
      )
    }

    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleToggleWishlist}
        className="ml-4 py-3 px-3 rounded-md flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-500"
      >
        {isInWishList && found ? (
          <HeartIcon className="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-red-600" aria-hidden="true" />
        ) : (
          <HeartIcon className="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0" aria-hidden="true" />
        )}
        <span className="sr-only">
          {isInWishList ? "Eliminar de favoritos" : "Agregar a favoritos"}
        </span>
      </button>
    );
  };
```